# Changing Google Maps V3 Maker Icon the correct way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

The code in example 1 works. I would like to understand the marker.setIcon(); function more (new to JavaScript also).

My question is. In the documentation for Google maps you see something like this for changing the marker.

```
MarkerImage(url:string, size?:Size, origin?:Point, anchor?:Point, scaledSize?:Size)
```

How does this relate to what I have done in example 1 for setting up marker Icon, shoud I have done somethign like this instead?

```
marker = google.maps.MarkerImage({
        url: "newIcon.png"
});

marker.setIcon(marker);
```

and would that have worked?

here is my example

Example 1

```
function initialize(){
//MAP

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('xxx','xxx');
  var options = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });     

  marker.setPosition(latlng);
  marker.setIcon("newIcon.png");
  map.setCenter(latlng);

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You're giving a V2 answer for a V3 question.

There is no GIcon in V3.

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("newIcon.png");
```

Can be used inside your marker as the icon.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        icon:image
    });
```

Comment: thanks! so how would you do to change the marker icon when its already created? I tried marker.setIcon(); but no luck...

Comment: I think you're correct. I just tried it. marker.setIcon(image2); works fine for me. Where image2 = google.maps.MarkerImage("newIcon2.png"); Make sure you get a handle to your marker.